# fc.exe: command line tool in windows 8

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I need to compare two text file and get the lines which are different.

I used

> fc file1.txt file2.txt > fc.txt

I got the result but there is a problem:

If a line in any file is more than 128 character long, It breaks it into another line *(after 128th character)* and then compares.

Is this a commom problem?
*(this problem is not the same as this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953929)*

Comment: If you're running this under PowerShell, fc is an alias for Format-Custom.  You want to run `fc.exe`.

Comment: On my _retired_ Windows XP the `fc.exe` displays max. 381 characters of original lines broken to 3 lines, each max. 127 characters. Hereat different lines in compared files are more than 500 chars long... Appropriate PowerShell tool could be [Compare-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/compare-object.html) that I didn't experience in this context.

Comment: @KeithHill, you should totally add your comment as an answer to the question. Helped me! Thanks.

Comment: @MarioTacke Sure thing.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running this under PowerShell, `fc` is an alias for the `Format-Custom` command. You want to run `fc.exe`.

Comment: No. I am using `fc` in cmd, not in PowerShell. So, This is not an answer to my question, and it should be a comment. Also, My question title says "fc.exe: ... "