# File comparison using command prompt

Tags: windows-7, cmd

I wanted to compare two text files using command prompt and I am using two text files with name abc and xyz. I need unique records in other text file. But the output which I get for some string are going on to second line which breaks my urls into two separate lines is there any way to compare them and get output in the same format which in the existing text file.

```
fc abc.txt xyz.txt > unique.txt
```

abc File contains data as below

```
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-Bank-opens-new-Minocqua-branch-5e1.aspx
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=75
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=76
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=202
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-Bank-finances-12M-for-retail-and-residential-projects-5dc.aspx
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-Banc-Corp-completes-purchase-of-risk-and-benefits-consulting-firm-Ahmann-Martin-Co-5db.aspx
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-opens-new-Rochester-branch-5da.aspx
```

xyz File contains data as below

```
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-Bank-opens-new-Minocqua-branch-5e1.aspx
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=75
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=76
newsroom.associatedbank.com/content/default.aspx?NewsAreaId=2&SubjectId=202
newsroom.associatedbank.com/News-Releases/Associated-opens-new-Rochester-branch-5da.aspx
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate [fc.exe: command line tool in windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27484208/3439404). See my comment there, now  checked up on `Win-8` as well

Comment: Is there any solution for  this?

Comment: Truly, being on `XP` at that time, I didn't look for. Try _Powershell_ ...

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Pleaqse [edit] your question to include unique .txt

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to download `Windows PowerShell 2.0` if you have `Windows 7` because it is already installed.

From `cmd.exe` command line:

```
powershell Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content abc.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content xyz.txt)  –IncludeEqual ^| Out-File -FilePath unique.txt -Width 4096
```

Notes:

- remove `–IncludeEqual` (added for piquancy only);
- note that `|` pipe is `^|` escaped to pass it to PowerShell, not to treat it in `cmd`;
- change `-Width 4096` to desired output line length (integer range). Any additional characters are truncated, not wrapped. If you omit this parameter, the width is determined by the characteristics of the host. The default for the Windows PowerShell console is 80 (characters);
- here is a huge [script repository](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=storage&f%5B0%5D.Text=Storage&f%5B1%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=files&f%5B1%5D.Text=Files&f%5B2%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B2%5D.Value=PowerShell&f%5B2%5D.Text=PowerShell) there (the link provided with filter to file manipulation with *PowerShell*);
- here is a [Compare-Object Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) reference.

To see `SideIndicator` output format, omit `^| Out-File ...` as follows. You should get truncated output on your screen.

```
powershell Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content abc.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content xyz.txt)  –IncludeEqual
```

Using [alias names for Cmdlets](http://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) and omitting optional parts of *PowerShell* statements, next command should give the same result:

```
powershell diff  (type abc.txt)  (gc xyz.txt) -includeequal
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you try

```
findstr /i /L /x /v  /g:xyz.txt abc.txt > unique.txt
```

which should report any line in `abc.txt` that isn't present in `xyz.txt` (`/i` ignoring case, `/L` literally, no regex, `/x` - exact match, not on part-line `/v` lines which don't match)

Consequently, any lines in `abc.txt` that **don't** appear in `xyz.txt` will be directed to `unique.txt` (tks JosefZ)

Comment: Well done, but `/X` switch means  _Print lines that match exactly_. Use `/V` instead (or moreover?): _Print only lines that do NOT contain a match_ as the OP needs _unique records in_ other _text file_. Consider to run twice with 1. `/g:xyz.txt abc.txt > unique.txt` and 2. `/g:abc.txt xyz.txt >> unique.txt`...

Comment: I need only unique records which are in abc.txt file but still I am unable to get that

Answer (score 0):

**"But the output which I get for some string are going on to second line which breaks my urls into two separate lines**"

`fc` has a bug when a line contains more than 127 characters.

It has been hotfixed for Windows XP and Windows Vista but not for Windows 7.

It does not work correctly in Windows 7 (using either the 32 or 64 bit `fc.exe`)
when the command compares files that contain any ASCII or UNICODE records that have more than 127 characters in a record.

---

Source [where are known errors in fc.exe for windows 7 published](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/where-are-known-errors-in-fcexe-for-windows-7/53bd425e-4270-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

> I have created two test files xxx.txt and yyy.txt which differ at line nnn, but fc/n reports that they differ at line nnn+1. It appears that fc has split an  of the earlier line into two lines. Examining the files with a hex editor shows no trace of end of line characters 0D or 0A at the place where fc is splitting the line. For larger files the reported mismatch locations  from fc and the actual lines where the mismatches are occuring get badly out of synch.
>   Is this an already known error in fc, and where is there a published list of such known problems with this program?

...

There are hot fixes for Windows XP and for Windows Vista. I do not see one for Windows 7
.

> Article ID: 953930 - The Fc.exe command does not work correctly on a Windows XP-based computer when the two files that you are comparing have the TAB or SPACE character around the 128th byte in a string of characters
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953930
>
> Article ID: 953932 - The Fc.exe command does not work correctly in Windows Vista or in Windows Server 2008 when the two files that you are comparing have the TAB or SPACE character around the 128th byte in a character string
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953932

Comment: "There are hot fixes for Windows XP and for Windows Vista. I do not see one for Windows 7" - the hotfixes were released in 2008. W7 was released in July 2009, so we'd presume the fix was rolled forward.

Comment: I tried the OP's issue on Windows 7 and got the same result. It would appear that it has not been fixed in Windows 7.