# Issue with comparison using cmd

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to compare two files and get its result in other file. For this I am using the below command

```
findstr /vixg:C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Current\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt > C:\output.txt
```

Both files have the following data:

```
bank.de/2013/gb/serviceseiten/dateisammlung/files/collection.php?action=add&file[]=dbfy2013_gesamt.pdf
```

I think the issue is with [] which is in the given url. How can I ignore all such special cases or include them in comparison too?

Comment: I would use `fc /c file1.txt file2.txt>nul` (`%errorlevel%`: 0=identical, 1=different, 2=file not found)

Comment: This has a limitation that it cannot compare more then 256 character. Is it right?

Comment: `fc` means `F`ile`C`ompare. Just tried it with two nearly identical 15MB files (changed one of the very last characters in the second one)

Comment: I compared the file keeping one new url and the output was perfect but the only issue here is the mail url goes to the second line. Below is the output Comparing files 
geschaeftsbericht.deutsche-bank.de/2013/gb/serviceseiten/dateisammlung/files/collection.php?action=add&file[]=dbfy2013_financ_d
ata_supplement_4q.pdf

*****

Comment: `if %errorlevel%==1 type file2.txt>output.txt` ?

Comment: I am getting error as invalid switch

Comment: put your filenames into quotes: `"file1.txt"`

Comment: This is my command C:\Users\anoopn>fc /c C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Current\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt>C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\new.txt (%errorlevel%: 0=identical, 1=different, 2=file not found)

Comment: I just read your old questions, which put a complete different light on this. @Magoos [Answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28738581/2152082) should work fine. The key is the  `/L`-switch.

Comment: /L switch works thanks a ton

Comment: Then I suggest, you accept [Magoos answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28738581/2152082) and delete your other questions with this topic to keep thís site clean.

Comment: What does this /L stands for?

Comment: `/L` = literal search. Try `findstr /?` to read it in your language.

Answer (score 0):

```
fc /c "C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Current\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt" "C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 echo files are identical
if %errorlevel%==2 echo at least one of the files was not found.
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo files are different.
  type "C:\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\113830_b8ed6819-18f5-464b-845e-32f1528e7376.txt">"C:‌​\Users\anoopn\Desktop\Prior\new.txt"
)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use it, can you help me with it.

Comment: Its giving false result